# How to get A function to work for each button made in table

Tags: javascript, html

Im creating an alert page that allows users to tell if an alert is acknowledged or unacknowledged. I created a function that changes the buttons text whenever you click on it and currently the function only works for the first row in the table. How do I get my function created to work in each table row

```css
body {
    background-image: url("BackgroundAxure.png");
    background-color: #f2f0ed;
    position: auto;
}
table th:nth-child(3), td:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}

body {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

#Logo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    height: 46px;
    display: flex;
}
#sort{
    height: 20;
    width: 40;
}
#h1 {
    text-align: right;
    color: black;
    font-size: 39px;
}
.button {
    background-color: green;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
}

table.dataTable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#seen {
    width: 160px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color : #E16A6A;
    border           : none;
    border-radius    : 4px;
    color            : black;
    text-align       : center;
    text-decoration  : none;
    display          : inline-block;
    font-size        : 14px;
}
#seen.hack { 
    background-color : green;
    color            : black;
}

table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable tfoot th {
    font-weight: bold;
}

table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable thead td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1, table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1 {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

table.dataTable.no-footer {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-left, table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-left {
    text-align: left;
}

table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-center, table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-center {
    text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-right, table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-right {
    text-align: right;
}

table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-justify, table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-justify {
    text-align: justify;
}

table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-nowrap, table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Search box */

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
    float: left
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input {
    margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0.755em;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    margin-left: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    *cursor: hand;
    color: #333 !important;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
    color: #333 !important;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #dcdcdc));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%)
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody {
    *margin-top: -1px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody th>div.dataTables_sizing, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody td>div.dataTables_sizing {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important
}

.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111
}

.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollHead table, .dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollBody table {
    border-bottom: none
}

.dataTables_wrapper:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
        float: none;
        text-align: center
    }
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
        margin-top: 0.5em
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
        float: none;
        text-align: center
    }
    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
        margin-top: 0.5em
    }
}
.popup{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
button{
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  transition: background 0.1s linear, border-color 0.1s linear, color 0.1s linear;
}
.view-modal{
    background-color: #1da4f1;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 22px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.popup{
  background: #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  top: -150%;
  max-width: 380px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.2);
  transition: top 0s 0.2s ease-in-out,
              opacity 0.2s 0s ease-in-out,
              transform 0.2s 0s ease-in-out;
}
.popup.show{
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: top 0s 0s ease-in-out,
              opacity 0.2s 0s ease-in-out,
              transform 0.2s 0s ease-in-out;

}
.popup :is(header, .icons){
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.popup header{
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebedf9;
}
header span{
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
header .close, .icons a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
header .close{
  color: #878787;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: #f2f3fb;
  height: 33px;
  width: 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#ExitBtn{
  color: #878787;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: #f2f3fb;
  height: 33px;
  width: 33px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6%;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 60%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Alert Page</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap.">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sty.css">
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertStyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v3.0.6/css/line.css">
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:20px auto">
  <div id="Logo">
    <img id="Logo_img" class="img " src="logo.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="h1_UserName">
    <p><img id="u_img" class="img " src="user.png" /><span>UserName</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="container"></div>
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp<img src="arrows.png"width="12" height="auto"/></th>
        <th>Hostname<img src="arrows.png"width="12" height="auto"/></th>
        <th>File<img src="arrows.png"width="12" height="auto"/></th>
        <th>File<img src="arrows.png"width="12" height="auto"/></th>
        <th>Change Agent<img src="arrows.png"width="12" height="auto"/></th>
        <th>Change Process<img src="arrows.png"width="12" height="auto"/></th>
        <th>App ID <img src="arrows.png"width="12" height="auto"/></th>
        <th>Acknowledge Alerts<img src="arrows.png"width="12" height="auto"/></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>04/02/22 12:37:00 PM</td>
        <td>HostName</td>
        <td>C:/B/</td>
        <td>C:/B/</td>
        <td>Change Agent</td>
        <td>Change Process</td>
        <td>Ap ID</td>
        <td><button id="seen">N</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>04/02/22 12:37:00 PM</td>
        <td>Name #1</td>
        <td>C:/B/</td>
        <td>C:/Programe_Files/</td>
        <td>JohnAcc</td>
        <td>Microsoft_Word</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td><button id="seen">Y</button></td>
        </div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      "pageLength": 4
    });
  });

  document.getElementById('seen').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  this.textContent = this.classList.toggle('hack') ?
    'Acknowledged' :
    'Unacknowledged'
}, false);

function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
    
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot use the same `id = "seen"` for every button. Use the class and `forEach()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You must change all your `id="seen"` to `class="seen"` and then do the following:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.seen');
for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener(
        "click",
        function (event) {
            this.textContent = this.classList.toggle("hack")
                ? "Acknowledged"
                : "Unacknowledged";
        },
        false
    );
}
```